# Spark: Iterate Subsets of Datasets by key (where clause)

Tags: java, apache-spark, foreach, dataset, rdd

I hope somebody can help me with a Spark-Problem.

I have a bunch of IDs in a Dataset (ds_ids), let’s say my Dataset looks like this:

```
ID
1
2
3
```

I’m collecting further data for these Ids and store them in a new Dataset (ds_combined_data), like:

```
ID       |      Date      |        Status
1        |   10.01.18     |         10
1        |   11.01.18     |         20
2        |   10.01.18     |         20
3        |   12.01.18     |         20
3        |   13.01.18     |         30
```

What I want to do now is to (parallel) process Subsets (by ID) of this Dataset by a method called processMethod, for example:

```
ID       |      Date      |        Status
1        |   10.01.18     |         10
1        |   11.01.18     |         20
```

Therefore, I’ve tried the following:

```
ds_ids.foreach((ForeachFunction<Long>) row -> {
                    this.processMethod(ds_combined_data.where(col("ID").equalTo(row.longValue())));
                });
```

i get the following Error:

```
User class threw exception: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 56.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 56.0 (TID 2651, local, executor 2) 
: java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.<init>(Dataset.scala:167) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$.apply(Dataset.scala:58) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withTypedPlan(Dataset.scala:2827) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.filter(Dataset.scala:1272) 
 at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.where(Dataset.scala:1300) 
 at SVDatenTransferJob.lambda$process$4a2a96b4$1(SVDatenTransferJob.java:184)
```

It seems that ds_combined_data cannot be accessed from inside the foreach-function.

So i did some research and it seems that it is not possible to access outer objects from inside a foreach-function.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this problem? Is there maybe a way to pass the variable/object ds_combined_data into the function?

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to do now is to (parallel) process Subsets (by ID) of this Dataset

If I understood well, you want to partition your dataset, so that each partition contains all the elements with the same ID. In Spark, you can do it with with `repartition` and `mapPartition`.

```
    ds.repartition(ds.col("ID")).mapPartitions(new MapPartitionsFunction() {
        @Override
        public Iterator call(Iterator iterator) throws Exception {
            // you can call processMethod passing iterator
            // Example of processing each Row of the iterator:
            while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                Row r = (Row) iterator.next();
                Integer id = r.getInt(0);
            }
            return iterator;
        }
    }, Encoders.kryo(Row.class)).show();
```

With `repartition(ds.col("ID"))` you will force Spark to reorganize your dataset so that you have one partition by ID. Then, with the `mapPartition` you can process each partition as an Iterator of Row. Finally, you must return another iterator. Note that you must specify an encoder for the type of object you are saving in your iterator. You can return Rows, basic types like Long or POJO types created by yourself.

Hope it helped!